# Different luminance of Python imshow with transposed data

Tags: python, transpose, imshow

This might be a trivial question.

I store a series of spectrum with 1025 frequency bins into a list, using which I want to plot by `imshow`. The [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1UyTlIs325wTG16aWNzVjZMLWs) is a list having 345 entries representing the number of time frames, each of which has 1025 dimensions representing frequency bins. The normal or conventional way to display the spectrogram is having x-axis as time frame and y-axis as frequency bin.

My attempts are as follows:

```
imshow(X, aspect='auto');show() 
imshow(np.array(X), aspect='auto');show() # Seems to be same as the first one.
# The correct display would be x-axis as time and y-axis as frequency bin,
# and the y-axis should be ordered from lower to upper.
imshow(np.array(X).T, aspect='auto', origin='lower');show()
```

However, the third plot seems to have dimmer luminance and it could be the issue of normalization. How does `imshow` behave differently with transposed data?

[image: The first output]
[image: The second output]
[image: The third output]

EDIT:

Trying to specify the figure size at the first place

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
imshow(np.array(X).T, aspect='auto', origin='lower')
```

[image]

Though the figure size alters the luminance of the image, the relative magnitude  of each component in y-axis doesn't look to be the same for me when compared to the former image, i.e., the first and second one. How exactly does `imshow` adjust the luminance with transposed data or different orientation?

Comment: Are you sure the luminance is really different at individual points?  It may just look dimmer because the luminous points are spread out over a wider area (since you changed the orientation of the plot), making them seem to be absorbed by the background.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I specified the figure size before the third one and it looks good. Thank you.

Comment: You could answer the question (either @BrenBArn or @Fredom) and accept it.

Comment: The behavior of `imshow` is still unclear with transposed data or reorientation. It seems the relative luminance between dimensions along the x-axis in the first two figures and that along the y-axis in the last figure is not consistent.